# How to write recursive number guess function?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to make a program that uses recursion to guess a number the user is thinking of. I am a bit stumped. I am having trouble with the second block of code, the `def binarySearch(bottom,top)` function. The program is supposed to start out by guess 50. If "N" then it asks if greater or lower. If G then it should ask 75. And so on and so on. I am having trouble setting the values to different answers. Also, how should I go about so it will not give me float point?

```
def guess(x):
    response = input("Is the number " + str(x) + "? Enter Y/N:\n")
    if response == "Y":
        print("YAY!  I got it!")
        return response
    else:
        print("BOO. . . Ok, I'll keep trying.")
        response = input("Is the number greater than or less than " + str(x) + "?Enter        G/L:\n")
    while  response != "G" and reponse != "L":
        print("Sorry, that isn't a valid response/")
        response = input("Pleae try again. Enter G/L:\n")
    return response
```

```
def binarySearch(bottom,top):
    if bottom == top: #base case
        return bottom

    elif guess(top+bottom/2) == "G":
        top = top + bottom 
        return binarySearch(middle,top)

    elif guess == "L":
        top = (top/2)
        return binarySearch(bottom,top)

    binarySearch(bottom,top)
```

Comment: where does binarySearch link with your first block of code?

Comment: Where have you defined middle in your `binarySearch` function?

Comment: elif guess(top+bottom/2) == "G":    When I do this? When I compare is guess is == "G" when passed with those parameters?

Comment: `guess` is a function, so `guess == "L"` is never True

Comment: @NickLee, if my answer or someone else's was what you are looking for (or isn't), please give feed back or accept one :)

Answer (score 1):

To work with non floats, use `int(#number)`. This will convert a number to an integer.

The next thing that needs to be done is setting either boundaries on the number chosen. Either hard coded in, or open for the user to decide. This will allow for proper binary guessing. That is, binary search works by taking the value that is and the maximum known that is not.

If the number being guessed is greater, then the number returned should be the `(int(guessed number + top boundary)/2)`. The way it is in you're code, the division happens first. If the number being guessed is less, then we take our `int( (guessedNumber -minimal known boundary)/2 )`. Finally, if the number matches, we have a success.

Thus, there is a need to constantly be keeping four variables in check: the guess, the top boundary, the bottom boundary, and the actual number.

Regarding the recursion, make a variable newGuess based off of the user input. newGuess will  be the middle concept in your code, and should be the new low or new high depending on the outcome of the user response.